# How can I draw a network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I want to draw a network like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree
from pymnet import*
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

mst_pearson=mst_tree(pearson)
mst_kendall=mst_tree(kendall)
mst_tail=mst_tree(tail)

nx.draw(mst_pearson,pos=nx.spring_layout(mst_pearson))
plt.show()
```

mst_pearson is my own function to generate the minimum spanning tree of the graph,but my graph likes this although I set the layout:
[image]
How could I change the layout of nodes and the edges? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the function

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, [...])
```

you can use the  `pos` argument in order to set a specific layout.

For example I have this snippet code in order to do that inside a custom function

```
def custom_draw_graph_function(graph_layout='shell'):

    # these are different layouts for the network you may try
    if(graph_layout == 'spring'):
         graph_pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
    elif(graph_layout == 'spectral'):
         graph_pos=nx.spectral_layout(G)
    elif(graph_layout == 'circular'):
         graph_pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    elif(graph_layout == 'fruchterman'):
         graph_pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
    elif(graph_layout == 'shell'):
         graph_pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
    else:
         graph_pos=nx.random_layout(G)

     # DRAW GRAPH
     # Nodes
     nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,graph_pos,[...])

     [...]
```